# Unable to add legend to economic time series chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, quantmod, geom-text, economics

I'm attempting to add a legend to a time series chart and I've so far been unable to get any traction.  I've provided the working code below, which pulls three economic data series into one chart and applies several changes to get in a format/overall aesthetic that I'd like. I should also add that the chart is graphing the y/y change of quarterly data sets.

I've only been able to find examples of individuals using scale_colour_manual to add a legend - I've provided code that I put together below.

Ideally, the legend just needs to appear to the right of the graph with the color and line chart.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
library(quantmod)
library(TTR)
library(ggthemes)
library(tidyverse)

Nondurable <- getSymbols("PCND", src = "FRED", auto.assign = F)
Nondurable$chng <- ROC(Nondurable$PCND,4)
Durable <- getSymbols("PCDG", src = "FRED", auto.assign = F)
Durable$chng <- ROC(Durable$PCDG,4)
Services <- getSymbols("PCESV", src = "FRED", auto.assign = F)
Services$chng <- ROC(Services$PCESV, 4)

ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = Nondurable, aes(x = Index, y = chng), color = "#5b9bd5", size = 1, linetype = "solid") +
  geom_line(data = Durable, aes(x = Index, y = chng), color = "#00b050", size = 1, linetype = "longdash") +
  geom_line(data = Services, aes(x = Index, y = chng), color = "#ed7d31", size = 1, linetype = "twodash") +
  theme_tufte() + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent, limits = c(-0.01,.09)) +
  xlim(as.Date(c('1/1/2010', '6/30/2019'), format="%d/%m/%Y")) + 
  labs(y = "Percent Change", x = "", caption = "Seasonally Adjusted Annual Rate. Retrieved from FRED & U.S. Bureau of Economic Analysis") +
  ggtitle("Year-over-Year Spending Trend Changes of the US Consumer") +
  scale_colour_manual(name = 'Legend', 
                      guide = 'legend',
                      values = c('Nondurable' = '#5b9bd5',
                                 'Durable' = '#00b050',
                                 'Services' = '#ed7d31'), 
                      labels = c('Nondurable',
                                 'Durable',
                                 'Services'))
```

I receive the following warning messages when I run the program (the chart still plots though).

```
Warning messages:
1: Removed 252 rows containing missing values (geom_path). 
2: Removed 252 rows containing missing values (geom_path). 
3: Removed 252 rows containing missing values (geom_path).
```

Comment: With me it throws *Error in check_breaks_labels(breaks, labels) : object 'percent' not found*

Comment: Odd - I've edited my code to include all the packages that were loaded now.

Comment: Thanks, I had already loaded `quantmod`, `ggplot2` and `ggthemes`. What was missing was `scales`.

Comment: Did you see any error in the code that would cause scale_color_manual not to cast a legend?

Comment: No, I have tried several ways and none is working. I will get back to this tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons you are receiving this error:

1. The bulk are being removed because of your limits. When you use `xlim()` or `scale_y_continuous(..., limits = ...)` ggplot removes the values beyond these limits from your data before plotting and displays that warning as an FYI. After commenting out both of those lines, you will still see a message about removed values but a much smaller number. This is becuase
2. you have `NA` values in the first 4 rows of column `chng`. This is true in all 3 datasets.

For the scales to show, you need to put something differentiating the lines in the `aes()` as in `aes(..., color = "Nondurable")`. See if this solution works for you:

```r
ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = Nondurable, aes(x = Index, y = chng, color = "Nondurable"), size = 1, linetype = "solid") +
  geom_line(data = Durable, aes(x = Index, y = chng, color = "Durable"), size = 1, linetype = "longdash") +
  geom_line(data = Services, aes(x = Index, y = chng, color = "Services"), size = 1, linetype = "twodash") +
  theme_tufte() +
  labs(
    y = "Percent Change", 
    x = "", 
    caption = "Seasonally Adjusted Annual Rate. Retrieved from FRED & U.S. Bureau of Economic Analysis"
  ) +
  ggtitle("Year-over-Year Spending Trend Changes of the US Consumer") +
  scale_colour_manual(
    name = "Legend",
    values = c("#5b9bd5","#00b050","#ed7d31"),
    labels = c("Nondurable", "Durable", "Services"
    )
  ) +
  scale_x_date(limits = as.Date(c("2010-01-01", "2019-02-01")))
```

[image]

Comment: I've removed both `xlim(0)` and `scale_y_continuous()` and the legend still does not appear. Note - did not add any new packages.

Comment: I'm returning to this question after some time and noticed an issue... if we remove xlim()... what is the best way to adjust the X axis to start at say...year 2010.